# Socket programming: How to handle multiple clients in c

Tags: c, sockets

I need help with a program I am trying to write. This program is supposed to have 3 clients connect to it through sockets.

I am looking for some direction.

How can I wait for for the server program to connect to all 3 clients.

After how can I differentiate between connections. i.e. write to client 1 but not 2 or maybe write to all clients connects.

How to use fork().

I am able to write a server and client programs but I am having trouble thinking of a solution to multiple clients.

It would be great if someone could help me with this problem. thank you very much.

EDIT: so far I have the server program wait until 3 clients have connected. All 3 clients finish but the server program shows a "error reading from socket:bad file descriptor"

My client codes looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char router_no[256] = "0";
    int cost_to_router_0 = 0;
    int cost_to_router_1 = 1;
    int cost_to_router_2 = 3;
    int cost_to_router_3 = 7;

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Initial table for Router 0(Client)\n");
    printf("===================================================\n");
    printf("Destination Router    |Link Cost                  |\n");
    printf("===================================================\n");
    printf("Router 0              |%d                          |\n", cost_to_router_0);
    printf("Router 1              |%d                          |\n", cost_to_router_1);
    printf("Router 2              |%d                          |\n", cost_to_router_2);
    printf("Router 3              |%d                          |\n", cost_to_router_3);
    printf("===================================================\n");

    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;


    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    printf("\n");    
    printf("Clients Router Number: %s \n", router_no);
    printf("Cost to Router 0(Client): %d \n", cost_to_router_0);
    printf("Cost to Router 1(Server): %d \n", cost_to_router_1);
    printf("Cost to Router 2:         %d \n", cost_to_router_2);
    printf("Cost to Router 3:         %d \n", cost_to_router_3);
    printf("\n");

    //printf("Please enter the message: ");
    //bzero(buffer,256);
    //fgets(buffer,255,stdin);

    // Send Router Number
    n = write(sockfd,router_no,strlen(router_no));    
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");

    // Send Cost of Router 0 to other Routers     
    n = write(sockfd, &cost_to_router_1, sizeof(cost_to_router_1));
    n = write(sockfd, &cost_to_router_2, sizeof(cost_to_router_2));
    n = write(sockfd, &cost_to_router_3, sizeof(cost_to_router_3));

    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket"); 

    int cost_server_to_router_0 = 0;
    int cost_server_to_router_1 = 0;
    int cost_server_to_router_2 = 0;
    int cost_server_to_router_3 = 0;

    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd, &cost_server_to_router_0, sizeof(cost_server_to_router_0));
    n = read(sockfd, &cost_server_to_router_0, sizeof(cost_server_to_router_1));
    n = read(sockfd, &cost_server_to_router_2, sizeof(cost_server_to_router_2));     
    n = read(sockfd, &cost_server_to_router_3, sizeof(cost_server_to_router_3));

    printf("Costs of Router 1(Server) to other Routers\n");
    printf("Cost to Router 0:         %d \n", cost_server_to_router_0);
    printf("Cost to Router 1:         %d \n", cost_server_to_router_1);
    printf("Cost to Router 2:         %d \n", cost_server_to_router_2);
    printf("Cost to Router 3:         %d \n", cost_server_to_router_3);

    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);

    if ( cost_to_router_1 + cost_server_to_router_0 < cost_to_router_0)

        cost_to_router_0 = cost_to_router_1 + cost_server_to_router_0;

    if ( cost_to_router_1 + cost_server_to_router_1 < cost_to_router_1)

        cost_to_router_1 = cost_to_router_1 + cost_server_to_router_1;

    if ( cost_to_router_1 + cost_server_to_router_2 < cost_to_router_2)

        cost_to_router_2 = cost_to_router_1 + cost_server_to_router_2;        

    if ( cost_to_router_1 + cost_server_to_router_3 < cost_to_router_3)

        cost_to_router_3 = cost_to_router_1 + cost_server_to_router_3;


    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Updated table for Router 0(Client)\n");
    printf("===================================================\n");
    printf("Destination Router    |Link Cost                  |\n");
    printf("===================================================\n");
    printf("Router 0              |%d                          |\n", cost_to_router_0);
    printf("Router 1              |%d                          |\n", cost_to_router_1);
    printf("Router 2              |%d                          |\n", cost_to_router_2);
    printf("Router 3              |%d                          |\n", cost_to_router_3);
    printf("===================================================\n");


    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Remember that this is from a single handling client program that I wrote using tutorials I found. I need to be able to modify it to connect and keep connection to several clients

My server code is plain as follows

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

     int number_of_clients = 0;
     char router_no[256] = "1";
     int cost_to_router_0 = 1;
     int cost_to_router_1 = 0;
     int cost_to_router_2 = 1;
     int cost_to_router_3 = 10000; // This is set to 10,000 because there is not link
                                   // between router 1 to router 3 and/but infinity
                                   // is not a real number.

     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     // Socket is opened
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

     // Displays error if socket opening was not suscessful
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

     // Sets serv_addr to zeros
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

     // Sets port number to argument passed in call
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);

     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

     // Biding socket to an adress
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");

     listen(sockfd,5);

     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

     while (1)// start of while
     {

     while (number_of_clients < 3)
     {
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);

     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
          else number_of_clients ++;

     }

     bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Client Router's Number: %s\n", buffer);

     int cost_client_to_router_1 = 0;
     int cost_client_to_router_2 = 0;
     int cost_client_to_router_3 = 0;

     bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd, &cost_client_to_router_1, sizeof(cost_client_to_router_1));
     n = read(newsockfd, &cost_client_to_router_2, sizeof(cost_client_to_router_2));
     n = read(newsockfd, &cost_client_to_router_3, sizeof(cost_client_to_router_3));

     if (n < 0) error("Error reading from socket");
     printf("Cost from client to router 1: %d \n", cost_client_to_router_1);
     printf("Cost from client to router 2: %d \n", cost_client_to_router_2);
     printf("Cost from client to router 3: %d \n", cost_client_to_router_3);


     n = write(newsockfd, &cost_to_router_0, sizeof(cost_to_router_0));
     n = write(newsockfd, &cost_to_router_0, sizeof(cost_to_router_0));
     n = write(newsockfd, &cost_to_router_2, sizeof(cost_to_router_2));
     n = write(newsockfd, &cost_to_router_3, sizeof(cost_to_router_3));

     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     close(newsockfd);

     } //end of while
     close(sockfd);


     return 0; 
}
```

The server code it not working properly as I am missing the understanding of fork() and select()

Comment: post here whatever you have tried.

Comment: It's not concrete i have ideas but not sure how to implement them. For example I want to run the server program and wait for all 3 clients to connect to it. I'm just not sure how to count for the connections.

Comment: Before asking should try something. If you are able to handle single client server application, it means you know about the functionality of accept() select() syatem call. Do read carefully about all these calls if you don't.

Comment: @Yousaf I have the server waiting for 3 connections but then the 3 clients end their code and server shows a bad file descriptor error.

Comment: you need to post your code here.

Comment: @Yousaf Hopefully this shows what I have

Comment: It looks like you posted the code for the client, but you are asking questions about the server...?

Comment: @immibis you were right my apologies and now I posted both.

Comment: please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post), you ask too many question in one. It's not easy to answer. You should separate your questions next time.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I wait for for the server program to connect to all 3 clients.

By calling `accept` three times.

> After how can I differentiate between connections. i.e. write to client 1 but not 2 or maybe write to all clients connects.

They all have different file descriptors returned by `accept`. Your current server code forgets the first two (by overwriting `newsockfd`) and only stores the last one in `newsockfd`. Don't do that, for obvious reasons.

> How to use fork().

This is not specific enough to have an answer.

> All 3 clients finish but the server program shows a "error reading from socket:bad file descriptor"

That's because the server closes the last client's file descriptor (remember that it forgot the first two), then doesn't wait for another client (because `number_of_clients` is already 3), then tries to read from the file descriptor it just closed.

Comment: thank you for your reply. To fix the first I'll so a loop. 

after that is it possible to create an array of newsockfd ?

Comment: @GustavoPalomino Yeah? Same as an array of anything else. File descriptors are just numbers.

Comment: I am thinking about an array but that would mean i would have to change several things for the server program. 
I read that using fork() it creates a new process or something similar. Can it be used here and if so how?

Comment: @GustavoPalomino have a look at [man select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), network is hard to do for a beginner, good luck. And if you can read [man getaddrinfo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo)

Comment: @GustavoPalomino 1) fork can be used anywhere and 2) by writing `fork()`, but that's probably not what you wanted to know. `select` will help if you want to read from several file descriptors at once.

Comment: @immibis thank you very much. I am still struggling with this. This is beginning to be very frustrating because the logic i get., not the implementation.

Comment: @immibis how can i make a communication between two clients? I will be needing to send information between clients.

Comment: @GustavoPalomino Either by establishing a connection between them the same as a client/server connection (one "client" actually has to act as the server for this connection), OR by sending your information to the server and having the server send it to the right other client.

Comment: @immibis I realized that the easier step would be to use the server as the middle man. How i have to think of a way for the client to wait until it gets a new message. Would a read in in a loop be a good idea for this?

Comment: @GustavoPalomino Calling `read` is would wait until you get a new message, yes. (Or part of a message; the loop is important)